# What is the difference when calling attribute from interface vs static class

Tags: java

```
public interface AFEvent {
  public String UNKNOWN ="Unknown";
  public String ERROR = "EQUINOX_EVENT_ERROR";
  public String REJECT = "EQUINOX_EVENT_REJECT";
  public String ABORT = "EQUINOX_EVENT_ABORT";
}
```

And

```
public class AFEvent {
   public static final String UNKNOWN ="Unknown";
   public static final String ERROR = "EQUINOX_EVENT_ERROR";
   public static final String REJECT = "EQUINOX_EVENT_REJECT";
   public static final String ABORT = "EQUINOX_EVENT_ABORT";
}
```

Then I can call it in the same way.

Whats the difference when calling attribute from interface vs static class ?

Comment: No difference... both are `static` final variables that is class-level  variable.

Comment: It's better to keep your constants in an enum or final class rather than interface.

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP Why? You can implement multiple interfaces, making no need for a static import

Comment: @VinceEmigh Which is a horrible anti-pattern that has made the lives of many developers who happen to work on other people's code living hell. Don't do it, there's absolutely nothing to gain from it and it makes code hard to read.

Comment: Keep in mind interface always specify public access to members while in class you can control it (in range from public to private).

Comment: @biziclop That makes sense. Looked into it and read the passage on Effective Java about inappropriately using inheritence in this way (details leak into API and a lot of other unwanted things that aren't worth it). Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @VinceEmigh Josh Bloch managed to put it into less emotional words too, sorry for the outburst, but the memory of having to work on code that abused this to the maximum is too fresh :)

Answer (score 2):

fields declared in interface are by default `static` and `final`. So, no difference if they are to be used as final constants.

Answer (score 1):

On using `final` properties, there is no difference. The main difference between interfaces and classes is that on interfaces you can not provide a method implementation but only contracts, in order to force any class implementing your interface to provide implementations for those method contracts. On classes, you can provide method implementations (and contracts, if declared `abstract`).